# How to build my multi project Java software using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Java project I am developing on Linux, and I am using gradle to build it. I am scaling it up into multiple components, and I am rather lost.

Up to this point the project has been a single command line app built with gradle with a single src directory with all the java files in there. This now needs to change.

It will consist of three components.

A. A core java api.
B. A command line app that uses A.
C. And android app that uses A.

Right now A and B are just one giant src folder.

The java API will eventually be checked in as a stand alone open source library on Github.

What is the proper way to build this? I really have no clue where to start.

Should the core java api be built as a library by gradle and then output to the android and cli projects?

Or should the the other apps just add the core api as an include directory?

Or should I just use symlinks to add the core api code to the other builds?

To make this less of a subjective question, I am most interested in the one solution that will be conform to standard conventions, and the most idiomatic gradle approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to release 'A' as an open source library then you can try to go through the process of getting it **added to the Maven central repo** from where you can add it as any other dependency. I haven't tried it myself but I've read that it can be tedious.

Fortunately in Gradle it's also possible to **add a git repository as a dependency** to a project. [You can find the details under this announcement blog post](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies). So once you have 'A' pushed to a git repository, then you can add it as a dependency for both 'B' and 'C'.

Or you can build a jar from 'A' to wherever you please, including the original target directory and **include it as a local jar** in 'B' and 'C's build script

```
dependencies {
    implementation files("A_source_path/A_local.jar")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I think that is putting the cart before the horse. Right now the priority is developing on my local machine successfully. Releasing the library open source is a secondary priority down the road.

Comment: I have added another solution to add your local jar built from 'A'. At this point setting up a more complex solution that would yield the same result('A' being used as a dependency in the other two projects) doesn't make much sense to me. Especially if you are still figuring out the final structure.